# Can't generate png with Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures

Tags: math-mode, errors, equations, align

i am trying to generate pdf file from latex document with formula below

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\sqrt{2{{x}^{2}}-5x+2}}{3}\le x<0 \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{align}
&   x<0  ,\\
&   -3x\le \sqrt{2{{x}^{2}}-5x+2}
\end{align} \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{align}
&   x<0  ,\\
&   9{{x}^{2}}\le 2{{x}^{2}}-5x+2
\end{align} \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{align}
&   x<0  ,\\
&   7{{x}^{2}}+5x-2\le 0
\end{align} \right. \Leftrightarrow
\end{equation}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

and got error message

> ! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
>   (amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.
>
> See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>    ...
>
> l.10 \end{align}
>                   \right. \Leftrightarrow \left{ \begin{align}

any other formulas work fine. Please help

Comment: Don't use `align` inside `equation`. Use `aligned` instead.

Comment: Or rather the starred variant. Having a `varwidth` environment is a bit useless, ase you are using `standalone`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `align` inside `equation`. Use `aligned` instead. Also there is no need for `varwidth`. The `standalone` class provides that option itself.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
-\frac{\sqrt{2{{x}^{2}}-5x+2}}{3}\le x<0 \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{aligned}
&   x<0  ,\\
&   -3x\le \sqrt{2{{x}^{2}}-5x+2}
\end{aligned} \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{aligned}
&   x<0  ,\\
&   9{{x}^{2}}\le 2{{x}^{2}}-5x+2
\end{aligned} \right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{ \begin{aligned}
&   x<0  ,\\
&   7{{x}^{2}}+5x-2\le 0
\end{aligned} \right. \Leftrightarrow
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Harish, thank you for your answer. But i got this document from third side and cannot change content. Perhaps i can change but it means that i am must parse file before generate pdf.